# How do I force a user to change their password on first login in auto-install?

Tags: password, cloud-init

I'm netboot installing Ubuntu focal and I have all the basic stuff working without issue.  I use this template as the user-data yaml file and it makes the user, sets the password, and imports whatever ssh key I specify:

```yml
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  apt:
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
      uri: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
  identity: {
    hostname: <HOSTNAME>,
    password: <PWHASH>,
    realname: <USER>,
    username: <USER>
  }
  user-data:
    timezone: America/Los_Angeles
  keyboard: {layout: us, toggle: null, variant: ''}
  locale: en_US
  network:
    ethernets:
      mainif:
        match:
          macaddress: <MAC>
        set-name: eth0
      eth0:
        dhcp4: true
    version: 2
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: [ <SSHKEY> ]
    install-server: true
  version: 1
```

I want to make it so that the user must change their password on first login.

Things I've tried:

- Late command

  ```
  curtin in-target --target=/target --passwd --expire <USER>
  ```

  This fails because late commands apparently execute before users are created, even though the documentation says

  > Shell commands to run after the install has completed successfully and any updates and packages installed, just before the system reboots.`

  The installer crashes, and I see in the crash report `/var/crash/$date.unknown.crash` that the command failed with exit status 1.  Manually logging in, chrooting to /target, and trying the command confirms it, saying that user 'dan' doesn't exist, and it doesn't show up in /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow:

  [image: snip of chroot /target, looking for any evidence of the specified user being created]

- Using `chpasswd: {expire: True}` in the identity section

  The installer crashes, saying that chpasswd is unexpected.
- using bootcmd

  This is silently ignored
- using a late command to write a cron in /target

  ```
   - /usr/bin/echo "@reboot root /usr/bin/passwd --expire dan && rm /etc/cron.d/update-pass" > /target/etc/cron.d/update-pass
  ```

  This does the job, but seems super fragile and extremely difficult to maintain.

Does auto-installer have built-in functionality for this that I haven't found?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I'm going to leave what I shared below, but I realized that I fixated on you wanting to change the user creation options when you really want to force the user to change password on first login.

It appears `cloud-init` does have an expire password option.  Therefore, you can still use `late-commands` to modify the file `/target/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data`.

https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#set-passwords

> By default, all users on the system will have their passwords expired (meaning that they will have to be reset the next time the user logs in)

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/11fa714f3a7b031657b642d0c2f0155854d5ee0e/cloudinit/config/cc_set_passwords.py#L219), that statement only seems to apply to users where the password is specified with `chpasswd`.  Appending configuration like the following to `user-data` might force the user to change password on next login

```
chpasswd:
    list: |
        <USER>:<PWHASH>
```

**Original Post below**

You'll have to do something like use `late-commands` to call `sed` to modify the file `/target/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data`.

The server installer, *subiquity*, takes your `autoinstall` configuration and creates `cloud-init` configuration to be used on first boot.  However, *subiquity* only supports a subset of what `cloud-init` can actually do.  Looking at the source code, you can see where *subiquity* actually hard-codes this setting to `'lock_passwd': False,`

https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/a76581cd2b973b55e55c6ac05b5bf47168493140/subiquity/models/subiquity.py#L197

You are unable to change the user in `late-commands` because the user does not exist yet.  The user gets created on first boot by `cloud-init`.

This snippet is untested, but `autoinstall` configuration like this should do what you want

```
late-commands:
    - sed -ie 's/lock.passwd.*/lock_passwd: true,/' /target/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data
```

Minor detail.  Depending on the *subiquity* version, the `user-data` file may contain `lock_passwd` or `lock-passwd`.  The regex `lock.passwd` should match both and `cloud-init` wants `lock_passwd`.  There was a bug in the initial *20.04* release - https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/pull/784